# If appears in my handlebarsand and doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I try using a if im my *.handlebars. I use this :

```
<% if({{status_ticket}} == "fechado"){ %>
 <td><span class="badge badge-outline-success">{{status_ticket}}</span></td>
<% } else{ %>  
 <td><span class="badge badge-outline-dark">{{status_ticket}}</span></td>
<% } %>
```

but the if no works and apper in my html page :

[image]

What's my error ?

Comment: Could You provide link to the repo  please? ;-)

Comment: I cant becase is a private repository. But i can share a [drive folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12YwwodTphZKwncFtV3awPjxQmY-XnJu9?usp=sharing) with the files. I cant change the repositore to public because i dont have permission